# Parse a remote JSON file using header in Angular 5

Tags: html, json, angular, angular5

I need to parse a remote JSON file using a header with a get request in **Angular 5**. Not sure how to do it with **GET** along with **header**.

Something like this but in **Angular 5**:

```
let headers = new Headers({
  'key': 'Value',
  'key2' :'value2'
});
let request_option = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers});
this.http.get("http.//.....", request_option)
.map(res => res.json()

this.user.firstname = user.response.docs[0].FIRST_NAME;
this.user.lastname = user.response.docs[0].LAST_NAME;
```

JSON:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
      "status":0,
        "QTime":1,
    },"response":{
    "docs":[{
            "FIRST_NAME": "John",
            "LAST_NAME": "Smith"
}]          
    }
  }
```

& finally be able to call it in HTML:

```
<div>{{user.firstname}}</div>
```

Comment: You are using AngularJS not Angular

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to archieve, but I can't see parJson function nor the your json corresponds to a list of users.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example for getting json from another server

```
$scope.userData = undefined;
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30&nat=US',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        };

        $http(req).then(function (response) {
            $scope.userData = response.data;
        });
```

If the response.data is recieved in json string, you can easily parse it using following code

```
JSON.stringify(response.data)
```

Below is the working example for getting json from another server and display it in table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      angular.module("testApp", ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.userData = undefined;
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30&nat=US',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        };

        $http(req).then(function (response) {
            $scope.userData = response.data;
        });
      }]);


    }());
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <form name="commonForm">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th> Name </th>
          <th> Gender </th>
          <th> Email </th>
          <th> Username </th>
          <th> Date of Birth </th>
          <th> Registered Date </th>
          <th> Phone </th>
          <th> Mobile </th>
          <th> Nationality </th>
          <th> Profile </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in userData.results">
          <td> {{user.name.first}} {{user.name.last}}</td>
          <td> {{user.gender}}</td>
          <td> {{user.email}}</td>
          <td> {{user.login.username}}</td>
          <td> {{user.dob}}</td>
          <td> {{user.registered}}</td>
          <td> {{user.phone}}</td>
          <td> {{user.cell}}</td>
          <td> {{user.nat}}</td>
          <td> 
            <img ng-src="user.picture.large">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer works fine for `angularjs` but the OP asked for `angular 5`.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 5 you can use property binding to access properties of DOM elements, in test case:

> `<div [innerHTML]="post.body"></div>`

for reference look here [angular.io docs](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts)